# Why std::isdigit accepts int?

Tags: c++, char

I'm confused why [isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and other functions in cctype header accepts int as a parameter, though they supposed to work with characters. To be able to work with any types of chars, including unicode?

Comment: A character **is** an `int`. Beginners assume that it is a `char` because of the similar name. Almost (perhaps all) the C library functions that take or return a character use the `int` type. I suggest you experiment with `printf("%zu\n", sizeof 'c');`

Comment: Essentially so it can handle EOF.

Comment: Probably because `EOF` is defined as `-1`.  A `char` may not be `signed`.

Comment: i removed the C tag, because even though it is inherited from C, `std::isdigit` is a C++ function from the C++ header `<cctype>`. You could ask similar for `isdigit` in C, but thats a different question (though with probably very similar answer ;)

Comment: The tags keep changing... but the title does say `std::`

Comment: @WeatherVane before posting this question I was google phrases like "C++ char is int", but didn't find explanation about

Comment: Sorry, my comment was about C before the tags changed. I can't comment on C++ but you might like to try the `printf("%zu\n", sizeof 'c');` mentioned.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've tried. As expected, it gives 1, same for all "basic"(ANSII?) symbols. But for unicode characters  like printf("%zu\n", sizeof 'が');  it's 4

Comment: When the tags were C and C++ someone replied to my comment "not in C++" but deleted it when the tag changed to C. It was then changed to C++. It would help if you tag the correct language to start with. C is not C++ and there is no C/C++ language.